# Is the function f constant?

Tags: analysis

Can you check the following?:

> Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a connected open set and $f\in C^2(\Omega)$ harmonic. Show that if f has an extrema in $\Omega$ so is f constant.

Can I say that because f is harmonic: $f''=0$ so $f'$ is constant. If now f has an extrema in $X$ so $f'(X)$ has to be $0$, because $f'$ is constant so complete $f'=0$. So f is constant. Did I miss something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you missed quite a bit. What is $f''$ supposed to mean?

Comment: the second derivation of f?

Comment: But you're in several variables. Note that you haven't even used the "$f$ has an extremum" hypothesis.

Comment: But I said: 
>If now $f$ has an extrema in $X$ so $f′(X)$ has to be $0$"

so I used that.
Why is it important that f has multible variables?

Comment: OK, my bad on the extemum comment. On your second question: $f''$ makes no sense. There are lots of second derivatives. In $\mathbb R^2$ we have $f_{xx},f_{yy}, f_{xy}$ And the Laplacian isn't even a second derivative. It is $f_{xx} + f_{yy}.$

Comment: I forgot about the definition of harmonic. My mistake.
So the laplacian is just $div(grad(f))$.which is in this case $0$.
grad f is $0$ for a certain $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: How can I proceed here?

Comment: Use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#The_mean_value_property. This shows that the set $A$ where $f$ equals the extremum is open; as $A$ is also closed, you are in business.